# jQuery handle Ajax timeout even after reloading page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ajax request cached for 1 minute. Meaning that no additional requests should be made when you reload the page during this time.

What would be a correct way to:

- After first page load, sets Ajax timeout for 1 minute.
- If user reloads page before that 1 minute has gone past, values of ajax should stay the same.

Ajax on document ready -

```
    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     dataType: 'json',
     url:"",
     cache: true, //It must "true" if you want to cache else "false"
     //async: false,
     success: function (data) {
        var resData = JSON.stringify(data.items);
        var items = JSON.parse(resData);
        console.log(data.totalItems);

    $('button.cart').append('<span class="cart-info">' +data.totalItems+ ' Items in your cart ' + '<span class="totalPrice-cart">€' + data.totalPrice + '</span></span>');
        $.each(items,function(i,v){
             console.log(v.name);
              console.log(v);
             $('ul.dropdown-cart').prepend(
                '<li>'+
                    '<div class="item">'+
                        '<div class="item-left">' +
                            '<img src="'+ v.imgSrc +'" style="width:100%; height:auto;" alt="">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="item-middle">' +
                            '<div class="cart-title text-uppercase">'+ v.name + '</div>' +
                            '<div class="cart-price">'+ v.qty + ' x € ' + v.price + '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="item-right">' +
                            '<button class="cart-delete "><img src="../public/img/web/Delete.png" alt=""></button>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>'+
                '</li>'

                );


         });
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
    alert("Error Happened!");
    }
    });
```